# Should annotations from IngressClass be applied to Ingress itself?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I am a bit confused with the way how IngressClass works. I moved all annotations for ALB to IngressClass and made it the default one, however, I noticed that load balancer cannot be created as the certificate couldn't be found.

Default IngressClass:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:000045211111:certificate/ee65c0af-044b-4c48-abc6-b4b44d4a3c76
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/wafv2-acl-arn: arn:aws:wafv2:ap-southeast-2:000045211111:regional/webacl/waf-api-regional-1e3042/d495cc4f-b24f-4465-afb4-ae5df32acb56
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: alb-default
spec:
  controller: ingress.k8s.aws/alb
```

When I move all these annotations to Ingress itself, the load balancer can be created successfully. I thought that annotations are taken from IngressClass and applied to Ingress itself when it is created.

I managed IngressClass from the terraform and populate these values during the infra provisioning so that I don't need to copy ARNs for the resources again and provide them when deploy service to k8s with Helm.

Am I missing anything? Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb`

Comment: @Adiii, I tried with and without it. Didn't work. It is an old annotation that is deprecated after 1.18 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: anything in the controller logs? or any event in the ingressclass?

Comment: Yes, certificate cannot be found as it is HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/pull/2963
solved this issue in this merge request